# Moments of a complex Gaussian Random Variable and their magnitudes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Moments of Gaussian Random variable with **zero mean** and  **σ^2** variance, is given by is given by

Let X be zero mean Gaussian with variance $ σ^2 $
Then the moments $  E[H^k] $ are as follows:

as X is complex so $ H = X + jY $

Source of this question is here 
 [a link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541169/what-is-variance-of-x2-varx2-or-i-need-eh4-explained-below/)

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\\  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ E   {\{H^k}\}       =  \        1,3 ...\  (k-1) \sigma^k \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ k \ \ \ \ even$

$ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ k\ \ \ \ \ \ \   odd$
$\ \\$

$E[H^4]=E[X^4-6X^2Y^2+Y^4]=0 $

$E[|H|^4]=E[X^4+2X^2Y^2+Y^4]=8\sigma^4. $

How is it equal to $  8\sigma^4 \ \ ? $ This is magnitude of $ \ |E|  $

Comment: Could you tell us what $Y$ and $H$ are?

Comment: Sorry Ravi, I corrected it now. Please check again @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: There is a mistake. It is not $8 \sigma^{4}$.

Comment: Dear Ravi, Kindly look into this.https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3541169/what-is-variance-of-x2-varx2-or-i-need-eh4-explained-below?noredirect=1#comment7282529_3541169 
Question comes from here @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: There seems to be a mistake there. The correct value is $14\sigma^{4}$.

Comment: Kavi, I'd love to see it whether 14 or 8, But how. Kindly answer that. I will happily accept that @KaviRamaMurthy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$EX^{4}=(1)(2)(3)\sigma ^{4}=6 \sigma ^{4}$. Also $EY^{4}=6 \sigma ^{4}$ and $2EX^{2}Y^{2}=EX^{2}EY^{2}=2\sigma^{4}$. Adding these we get $14 \sigma^{4}$.

Comment: $ 2EX^{2}Y^{2}=EX^{2}EY^{2}=2\sigma^{4} $ ,


Does expectation holds this property. $ E[X^4] = E[X^2] * E[X^2] $
I think, Noo. 

May be correct me if I am wrong. Kindly explain how you did that $ 2EX^{2}Y^{2}=EX^{2}EY^{2}=2\sigma^{4} $

Comment: Dear people, Consider this answer correct as I made mistake in formula and now I edited it. Thank you @Kaviramamurthy